# How to calculate the radius of lat long android?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app, I want to implement a feature if I reached within the radius of 50 meters as per given lat long i want toast to show.
I am not getting any idea how to calculate the radius of current lat long and how to implement, Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Geofence api in android to get alert when enter or exit in given range of given lat long

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. It might help

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
 .center(new LatLng(lat,lng))
 .radius(50)
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have to show the alert not to show on Map.

Comment: then you'll have to add mapListener to your map and  get the latLng of touch coordinates

Comment: ' mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) { Write your logic here}
});'